# PrimeNG controls not working inside angular2 form

Tags: angular, primeng

I created a form in angular2 and I used PrimeNG components inside the form but it's not working. Without form control it's working fine.

I am using angular latest version and PrimeNG 1.0.0-beta.16 version.

```
<form #todoForm="ngForm" *ngIf="true">
     <div class="ui-g">
            <div class="ui-g-5">
                <input [(ngModel)]="todo.todo" placeholder="What needs to be done?" pInputText style="margin-top: -5px;" size="30"/>
                <button pButton [disabled]="!todoForm.form.valid" type="text" (click)="addItem(todo)" icon="fa-plus" label="Add Task"></button>
            </div>
     </div>
</form>
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: What exactly isn't working? Any error message in the console?

Comment: @AlexanderCiesielski - getting an exception "If ngModel is used within a form tag, either the name attribute must be set or the form
      control must be defined as 'standalone' in ngModelOptions."

Comment: There you have the answer.  Put a name attribute on the control, e.g. name="todo"

Comment: I ignored :). You are right. Thank you @AlexanderCiesielski